# Use the definition to find the derivative of $g(x)=x^3$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Use the definition to find the derivative of $g(x)=x^3$.
        We consider 
            $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x^3-x_0^3}{x-x_0}$
        where $x_0$ is an accumulation point of the domain $D$ and $x_0 \in D$. We choose $\delta$ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ gives $|\frac{x^3-x_0^3}{x-x_0}|<\varepsilon$. We examine the following guessing that our limit is $3x^2$??

I am in analysis class so this isn't as simple as this problem at first seems though, it is very simply and I'm just having a brain malfunction. Thanks for the help!

Comment: $A^3 - B^3$ factors. $$ A^3 - B^3 = (A-B)(A^2 + AB + B^2). $$ Check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be very formal about this one I wanted to post an answer. Feel free to comment if it has any errors.

We begin with $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\frac{x^3-x_0^3}{x-x_0}$. From here we do a little simplifying so we may effectively guess at a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}x^2+xx_0+x_0^2$ so we guess our limit will tend to $3x_0^2$. From there we wish to find a $\delta$ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies we have $|x^2+xx_0+x_0^2-3x_0^2|< \varepsilon$.

We have
$|x^2+xx_0+x_0^2-3x_0^2|=|x^2+xx_0-2x_0^2|=|x^2+2xx_0-xx_0-2x_0^2|=|(x-x_0)(x+2x_0)|<|\delta(x+2x_0)|=|\delta(x-x_0+3x_0)|\leq|\delta|(|(x-x_0)|+|3x_0|$

and so we restrict $\delta<1$ giving $|\delta|(1+|3x_0|)<\varepsilon$ and so $\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{1+|3x_0|}$ therefore we select $\delta=min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+|3x_0|}\}$ and we are done.

Comment: Looks good to me. That said, I think it would generalize a little bit better (for instance to proving any given polynomial limit) if you simply split the terms up: you want to show $xx_0 \to x_0^2$ and $x^2 \to x_0^2$, so just group the terms that way: $|x^2+xx_0+x_0^2-3x_0^2|=|(x^2-x_0^2)+(xx_0-x_0^2)|$. Now use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

If $x_{o} \in D$, then
$$
\frac{g(x) - g(x_{o})}{x-x_{o}} = \frac{x^{3} - x_{o}^{3}}{x-x_{o}} = x^{2}+xx_{o} + x_{o}^{2} \to x_{o}^{2} + x_{o}^{2} + x_{o}^{2} = 3x_{o}^{2}
$$
as $x \to x_{o}$;
to prove that $f'(x_{o}) = 3x_{o}^{2}$ we have to appeal to the definition of limit that you write in your question.

Comment: I do not get the final assertion. It feels very not rigorous

Comment: Just opposite; it is to be very rigorous so you should appeal to the definition... Check your textbook again and then you will find out why I say so.

Comment: @az89: See this example: 1) Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}$; 2) Prove that the answer in 1) is the limit. First we may observe that $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$; this answers 1). But to check that 0 is indeed the limit we have to use epsilon-argument, which will answer 2).

Comment: I'm not following but I think I'm having a rough night. I'm going to call it and examine this tomorrow. I appreciate your help. Will mostly likely understand tomorrow morning and then accept the answer

Comment: Good luck and be not discouraged; for every person there is a transition time.

Comment: This doesn't involve $\delta$ at all so that is where this is lacking rigor for me. I think I came at this in slightly the wrong way.

Comment: @az89 Once you have that the ratio is $x^2+x x_0+x_0^2$, managing the epsilon-delta stuff is fairly routine. Namely, for $|x-x_0|<1$, $|x^2-x_0|^2<(2|x_0|+1)|x-x_0|$ and $|x x_0 - x_0|^2 = |x_0||x-x_0|$. These are not so bad to deal with. So take $\delta=\min \left \{ 1,\frac{\varepsilon}{3|x_0|+1} \right \}$.

Comment: Really we are just looking for the simplification and then considering the epsilon-delta part a given really?

Comment: @az89 At least that is what the answer above did. The actual epsilon-delta steps are not so difficult once you have reduced to polynomials.